# Power BI to DOMO

Tags: powerbi, report, domo

My company is moving to DOMO from Power BI as its single source of truth.

Does anyone have any pointers or things to look out for or best practise for moving reports already in Power BI into the new DOMO arena?

Answer (score 1):

I've established the best way is to extract dataset from Power BI report and use that as Data source for DOMO, obviously taking into account any existing data manipulation.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is :
1. Export Data From Power BI to local storage using PowerBI sdk using Python.
2. Import data from local storage to DOMO using DOMO sdk using Python.

The entire solution is bit complex which is perhaps could'nt be explained over here.