# Export existing dashboard from DOMO into Power BI

Tags: api, powerbi, extract, domo

Disclaimer: not a developer, but an analyst looking for solutions

I currently have a DOMO dashboard ready, am looking to port/replicate it on Power BI for another set of users who have the rest of their dashboards on Power BI. Is there a way I can do this?

Found a link with regard to having a writeback connector, is this the right one to go about doing it?:
https://domohelp.domo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360063090013-Power-BI-Writeback-Connector

Another similar(?) question on this forum:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Custom-Connector-with-Token-Refresh/m-p/2320423

The worst case scenario given to me, is to recreate the dashboard directly with the data source used in the DOMO dashboard (which I find the most intuitive as an analyst).

I could be trying to do the opposite of what the user here was trying to do from Power BI to DOMO:
[Power BI to DOMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350423/power-bi-to-domo)

Answer (score 0):

I see there being two options for your use case, you can move the data out of Domo to Azure / Power BI via the [Power BI Write-back Connector](https://domohelp.domo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360063090013-Power-BI-Writeback-Connector), which you have already identified, this can be automated and scheduled like a regular Domo process and is all managed and contained within the Domo UI, or, you could retain your data in Domo and have Power BI query it directly by via the [ODBC Data Driver](https://domohelp.domo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043437693-Domo-ODBC-Data-Driver).

The ODBC driver setup creates a DSN (Data Source Name) on your machine which references your Domo instance, allowing you to create queries against Domo directly. You can then [connect Power BI to that ODBC Connection](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/How-to-Connect-to-an-ODBC-Data-Source-From-Power-BI/ba-p/960701#:%7E:text=In%20Power%20BI%20Desktop%2C%20click,configured%20for%20your%20data%20source.).

I believe the visualisations would need to be re-created manually, I'm not aware of a tool that would let you port these across.